# When is a C++ expression well formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

Skimming through the C++ standard I came in quite a few cases to the statement:

> *The expression `X` shall be well formed.*

I said to my self "OK, intuitively you know what a well formed expression is, but can you give a formal explanation of what makes a C++ expression a well formed expression?".

I searched a little bit and I didn't find anything that gives a formal explanation on the matter. So here's my question:

**Q:** What are the qualitative characteristics of a well formed expression in C++?

Comment: @sharth I wouldn't: I would expect it to be the opposite of ill-formed. Whether an expression adheres to the rules in the C++ standard is not generally verifiable by a computer.

Comment: @sharth I'm not referring to a C++ program but rather to a C++ expression.

Comment: @sharth Heh, yet at the same time, the standard never actually specifies when a program is well-formed, only when it is ill-formed. Anyway, I wrote my comment because you spoke of the rules of the C++ language, not merely the diagnosable rules, and that's not generally verifiable: an expression may not be ill-formed yet still have undefined behaviour, and in that case, it doesn't follow the rules of the C++ language.

Comment: @sharth: A computer can absolutely determine whether a C++ program is well-formed.

Comment: @sharth: No, whether a program is well-formed is known at compile-time. User input has _nothing_ to do with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A well-formed expression must conform to the grammar for an *expression* (as defined by the standard) and must conform to the semantic rules, such as not using names which have not been declared, or not redeclaring a name in the same scope with a different meaning.

```
i = 0

X::i++
```

The expressions above are syntactically valid, but if `i` has not been declared, or is `const`, or `X` is not a namespace or class type, or `X::i` has not been declared, or `X::i` does not support post-increment, then they fail to meet the semantic requirements for a well-formed expression.

> Q: What are the qualitative characteristics of a well formed expression in C++?

See Clauses 1 to 15. You can't reduce the entire C++ language to a simple list.

Answer (score 8):

C++ Standard does not define *well-formed expression*, though it actually uses this phrase. There is definition of *well-formed program*

> 1.3.26 [defns.well.formed] **well-formed program**
>   C++ program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the One Definition Rule (3.2).

I guess we can assume that *well-formed expression* is an expression which does not make the program ill-formed (which is defined in 1.3.9 as *not well formed*).

Comment: `well-formed expression is an expression which does not make the program ill-formed`: That's very close to the intuitive explanation I gave to my self. But really, can we deduce some qualitative characteristics from this (e.g., 1. A well formed expression is compilable. 2... etc.)?

Comment: The standard does not define anything like that, and uses the phrase only in specific context, like "new-expression without including the header <new> is well formed". I really have no idea what would be item 2 in your list, and "compilable" means something like "constructed according to the standard".

Comment: The syntax and semantic rules for a `well-formed expression` are given in S5 of the Standard. They comprise about 40 pages, and would be hard to summarise in less.